# Jelastic Apache+mod_wsgi: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, apache, config, mod-wsgi, jelastic

I have unsuccessfully tried to install my Flask application to a Jelastic server. I have there Apache 2.4 and Python 3.5. The problem shows as a *500 Internal Server Error* when I try to access my "/" page.

**[Point 1.]** When restarting the Apache server, *apache2-python : actions* page shows some wrong values:

```
 Starting Python 2.4 cartridge (Apache+mod_wsgi)
 Application directory /opt/repo/ROOT selected as DocumentRoot
 $OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION=/opt/repo//ROOT/application file not found
  WSGI application was not found
```

I think application directory should be `/opt/repo/ROOT/stk_server`, which I have defined in /opt/shared/conf/etc/conf.d/openshift.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/opt/repo/"
DocumentRoot "/opt/repo/ROOT/stk-server"
WSGIScriptAlias / "/opt/repo/ROOT/stk_server.wsgi"
```

Why this does not apply when stating Apache? (In different manuals these paths are set in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ directory, but Jelastic environment doesn't have such.)

**[Point 2.]** my `/opt/shared/webroot/ROOT/stk_server.wsgi` file imports my application `/opt/shared/webroot/ROOT/stk_server/hello.py` using commands

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/opt/repo/ROOT/stk_server")
import os
os.chdir("/opt/repo/ROOT/stk_server")
from stk_server import hello as application
```

The `hello.py` is like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

print("Running my hello.py={}.".format(__name__))
print("My app={}.".format(app))

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, I love Python!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("Starting my hello.__main__")
    app.run()
```

The `error_log` shows these wsgi:errors:

```
Running my hello.py=stk_server.hello. 
My app=<Flask 'stk_server.hello'>. 
[remote 10...:228] mod_wsgi (pid=27564): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/repo/ROOT/stk_server.wsgi'. 
[remote 10...:228] TypeError: 'module' object is not callable 
[remote 10...:236] mod_wsgi (pid=27565): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/repo/ROOT/stk_server.wsgi'. 
[remote 10...:236] TypeError: 'module' object is not callable 
[remote 10...:228] mod_wsgi (pid=27564): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/repo/ROOT/stk_server.wsgi'. 
[remote 10...:228] TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What is this 'module' object? The same error occurs, when the project directory `/opt/shared/webroot/ROOT/stk_server` has a `__init__.py` file or not.

Comment: Could you please provide us with just an environment name so will be able to check?

Comment: Ours site should be http://stk-1.demo.datacenter.fi, if you mean that

Comment: Thanks, we will check and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

We have checked your environment and found incorrect imported "app" in the stk_server.wsgi file.
The right way:

```
from stk_server.hello import app as application
```

Have a nice day, Jelastic Support!